# How can I get my callback function to work?

Tags: c++, callback

I'm getting monitor information using `EnumDisplayMonitors`:

```
BOOL CALLBACK MonitorEnumProc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData){
  Class::callback(hMonitor,hdcMonitor,lprcMonitor,dwData);
  return true;
}

bool Class::callback(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData){
  classVar.appendData("callback");
  return true;
}

bool Class::f(){
  ...
  EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL,NULL,MonitorEnumProc,NULL);
  ...
}
```

`Class::callback` is static (if it isn't I get error C2352: illegal call of non-static function). This however causes problems with `classVar`: error C2228: left of '.appendData must have class/struct/union'. What should I be doing here to get around this problem (I want the callback to write data to `classVar`)?

Comment: Is `classVar` declared `static`?  If not, you need to operate on an instance; inside class-static functions there is no class instance to operate on.  It would be illuminating if you could share your `Class` definition

Comment: No it is not, it is written to fine within `f()`. I want `callback` to write to the same instance, is there any way of passing it through?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last parameter of [`EnumDisplayMonitors()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162610%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is an extra pointer reserved for use by the caller.  It is passed uninterpreted to the callback function.  Pass a pointer to the class instance.

```
BOOL CALLBACK MonitorEnumProc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData){
  reinterpret_cast<Class*>(dwData)->callback(hMonitor,hdcMonitor,lprcMonitor);
  return true;
}

bool Class::callback(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor){
  classVar.appendData("callback");
  return true;
}

bool Class::f(){
  ...
  EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL,NULL,MonitorEnumProc,reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(this));
  ...
}
```

Comment: Ah, `reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>` was what I needed!

Comment: @fredley: Note that cast between pointers and arbitrary integer types is totally unsafe.  However, `LPARAM` is guaranteed to be large enough to hold a pointer.  Some window messages (`WM_CREATE` comes to mind) use the `LPARAM` to pass pointers to lengthy structures.

Answer (score 2):

Use LPARAM dwData to provide pointer to the object. If there's more data to provide to callback then use auxiliary struct to put all data together and pass  pointer to this struct.

```
BOOL CALLBACK MonitorEnumProc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData)
{
  ((Class*)dwData)->callback(hMonitor,hdcMonitor,lprcMonitor);
  return true;
}

bool Class::callback(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor)
{
  classVar.appendData("callback");
  return true;
}

bool Class::f()
{
  ...
  EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL,NULL,MonitorEnumProc, (LPARAM)this);
  ...
}
```

EDIT: With auxiliary struct:

```
BOOL CALLBACK MonitorEnumProc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData)
{
  Class theClass = ((Auxiliary*)dwData)->theClass;
  RestOfData theRest = ((Auxiliary*)dwData)->theRest;

  theClass->callback(hMonitor,hdcMonitor,lprcMonitor, theRest);
  return true;
}

bool Class::callback(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, RestOfData* theRest)
{
  // use theRest
  classVar.appendData("callback");
  return true;
}

bool Class::f()
{
  ...
  Auxiliary theBundle(this, theRest);
  EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL,NULL,MonitorEnumProc, (LPARAM)theBundle);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dwData argument to pass in a pointer to your class instance, i.e. something like this (note: callback won't need to be static anymore - actually it becomes obsolete):

```
BOOL CALLBACK MonitorEnumProc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData){
  ((Class*)dwData)->callback(hMonitor,hdcMonitor,lprcMonitor);
  return true;
}

bool Class::callback(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor){
  appendData("callback");
  return true;
}

bool Class::f(){
  ...
  EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL,NULL,MonitorEnumProc,this);
  ...
}
```

Comment: I get `error C2664: 'EnumDisplayMonitors' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'Class *const' to 'LPARAM'`

Comment: Oh yes of course that will fail as I forgot the cast. Do "(LPARAM)this" when you call EnumDisplayMonitors

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes have this problem, and usually solve it through [function objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_C_and_C.2B.2B), they are more versatile that static functions, and you can create one which can memorize any parameter before being passed to MonitorEnumProc.